# gdb "watch" command breaks my loop?

Tags: gcc, gdb, conditional-statements, break, watch

First, I've got a infinite loop like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  int i=0;
  int b=1;
  while(b) 
  {
    ++i;
    printf("%d\n",i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile it, and run inside gdb, and break when "i==10", so I:

```
gcc 5.c -g && gdb a.out

(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005a3: file 5.c, line 3.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/console/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at 5.c:3
3     int i=0;
(gdb) watch i==10
Hardware watchpoint 2: i==10
(gdb) r
The program being debugged has been started already.
```

Well, the program seem to be terminated after "r". Why it doesn't break when "i==10"?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're watching your `auto` variable, the debugger needs to have the context available.

When you try to `run` the program again, gdb warns you: you'll lose the context and thus your hardware watchpoint (auto variables will be deallocated & reallocated).

`r/run` command runs the program from the start. You're mixing it up with `continue`. It's just that HW watchpoints on auto variables are cleaned up with a really unclear warning and it runs as infinite loop afterwards

To avoid this, there are several alternatives, all of them having their pros & cons:

- just perform `c` (continue) instead of `r`: your hw watchpoint will work: cons: you cannot type `r` (you'll survive)
- replace your hardware breakpoint by a *conditional breakpoint*: `b 5.c:9 if i==10` (line 9 is the line of the `printf`). cons: performance will suffer because the breakpoint will be triggered each time, and gdb decides to interrupt or not depending on the condition
- make g `i` global: allows to do what you wanted (restart) without a warning because in that case `i` isn't an auto variable. cons: global variables are not the best thing (specially when named `i` :))

Comment: Thanks, they are work for me. I was just confused why after setting watch or "if", program will be terminated if I use "r" command, without any print. I suppose "r" will run infinite loop and print a lot of messages?

Comment: if you use `r/run` command it runs the program from the start. You're mixing it up with `continue`. It's just that HW watchpoints on auto variables are cleaned up with a really unclear warning and it runs as infinite loop afterwards.